# Method works by itself, not when embedded in larger script

Tags: ruby

Here is the method and it's call:

```
def secret_formula(started)
  jelly_beans = started * 500
  jars = jelly_beans / 1000
  crates = jars / 100
  return jelly_beans, jars, crates
end


start_point = 10000
beans, jars, crates = secret_formula(start_point)
```

But when I call it embedded in this script, it gives me this error:

/Users/X/Documents/RUBY/ex26.rb:86:in `<module:Ex25>': undefined method`secret_formula' for Ex25:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/X/Documents/RUBY/ex26.rb:1:in `'

Here is the line from the error, and then the entire script:

```
beans, jars, crates = secret_formula(start_point)




module Ex25

  # This function will break up words for us.
  def Ex25.break_words(stuff)
    words = stuff.split(' ')
    return words
  end

  # Sorts the words.
  def Ex25.sort_words(words)
    return words.sort!
  end

  # Prints the first word after popping it off.
  def Ex25.print_first_word(words)
    word = words.pop
    puts words
  end

  # Prints the last word after popping it off.
  def Ex25.print_last_word(words)
    word = words.pop
    put word
  end

  # Takes in a full sentence and returns the sorted words.
  def Ex25.sort_sentence(sentence)
    words = Ex25.break_words(sentence)
    return words
  end

  # Prints the first and last words of the sentence.
  def Ex25.print_first_and_last(sentence)
    words = Ex25.break_words(sentence)
    Ex25.print_first_word(word)
    Ex25.print_last_word(words)
  end

  # Sorts the words then prints the first and last one.
  def Ex25.print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence)
    words = Ex25.sort_sentence(sentence)
    Ex25.print_fist_word(words)
    Ex25.print_last_word(words)
  end

  def secret_formula(started)
    jelly_beans = started * 500
    jars = jelly_beans / 1000
    crates = jars / 100
    return jelly_beans, jars, crates
  end

puts "Let's practice everything."
puts "You\'d need to know \'bout escapes with \\ that do \n newlines and \t tabs."

poem = <<END
\tThe lovely world
with logic so firmly planted
cannot discern \n the needs of love
nor comprehend passion from intuition
and requires an explanation
\n\t\twhere there is none.
END

puts "--------------"
puts poem
puts "--------------"


five = 10 - 2 + 3 - 6
puts "This should be five: #{five}"

puts
puts "----------"
puts


def secret_formula(started)
  jelly_beans = started * 500
  jars = jelly_beans / 1000
  crates = jars / 100
  return jelly_beans, jars, crates
end


start_point = 10000
beans, jars, crates = secret_formula(start_point)

puts "With a starting point of: #{start_point}"
puts "We'd have #{beans} beans, #{jars} jars, and #{crates} crates."

start_point = start_point / 10

puts
puts "----------"
puts

sentence = "All good things come to those who wait."
words = Ex25.break_words(sentence)
sorted_words = Ex25.sort_words(words)
Ex25.print_first_word(wrds)
Ex25.print_last_word (words)
Ex25.print_first_word(sort_words)
Ex25.print_last_word(sorted_words)
sorted_words = Ex25.sort_sentenc(sentence)
Ex25.print_first_and_last(sentence)
Ex25.print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

For a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), let's condense your script to this:

```
module Ex25
  def secret_formula(started)
    jelly_beans = started * 500
    jars = jelly_beans / 1000
    crates = jars / 100
    return jelly_beans, jars, crates
  end

  start_point = 10000
  beans, jars, crates = secret_formula(start_point)
  puts "With a starting point of: #{start_point}"
  puts "We'd have #{beans} beans, #{jars} jars, and #{crates} crates."
end
```

You might notice a problem: You're starting to run your calculations inside the module definition. In this context, `self` is `Ex25`, so calling `secret_formula` is looking for `Ex25.secret_formula`. But you've defined that method as an instance method with just `def secret_formula`, so it's not found. Edit to make it a module method (`def self.secret_formula`), and it will work just fine. At that point, you probably don't want your code running inside the module definition.

```
module Ex25
  def self.secret_formula(started)
    jelly_beans = started * 500
    jars = jelly_beans / 1000
    crates = jars / 100
    return jelly_beans, jars, crates
  end
end

start_point = 10000
beans, jars, crates = Ex25.secret_formula(start_point)
puts "With a starting point of: #{start_point}"
puts "We'd have #{beans} beans, #{jars} jars, and #{crates} crates."
```

Correctly indenting your code would probably have saved you in this situation. Your `puts` lines look like they're outside the module, but in fact the module doesn't close until that surprise `end` on the last line. Maybe you intended that `end` up higher where you unindented the rest of the file, and for `secret_formula` to be defined outside the module after all, without `def self.`? In either case, a little formatting goes a long way.